# How to install phonegap Facebook plugin for iPhone

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i'm making a project for school and I want to use the phone gap Facebook plugin for iOS, but the installation instructions in the text file is rather complicated. I was wondering if someone got a great link on how to install it, or maybe someone has an example project or even could help me with installing it because I fail extremely in installing it.

Kind Regards,
Bart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap posted a <strike>[**YouTube video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJZfqeXhEQM)</strike> detailing the install process step-by-step. Note that 1.4.1 is the most recent supported version of PhoneGap - the 1.5 Cordova update is not yet supported.

Answer (score 2):

I've created this tutorial / example for how to use Facebook inside of Phonegap without the plugin, it is similar but is more expandable and is easy to setup and use.

This explains everything in pretty good detail
http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=88

check out the GIT 
https://github.com/DrewDahlman/phonegapFacebookApp

hope this helps!